# Custom Item Field not showing up on form

Tags: netsuite

I have 2 custom item fields that will not show up on my custom item form.
I have moved them to the main tab, primary information and saved to the custom form.
When I go to the form they do not show up. They show up in the inline edit view of the item list but I cannot edit them there.

I have checked all of the following.

- permission level of items set to Edit for both access and searching
- I have made sure the display type is normal
- The custom list are populated
- my user role is administrator
- the form I am customizing is the same form I am viewing
- I am using the correct custom field (i.e item, as I created from the form customization window)
- I have logged out and logged back in
- I have tried using multiple select instead of list (these are both custom list)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

After a little trial and error, I found that I needed to select Assembly/Bill Of materials (I selected Subtype of Both purchase and sale). My assumption was that because the field was available to the Form Customization ui that I had selected everything I needed.

steps to fix:

- Edit Custom Item Field
- Applies To (subtab)
- Assembly/Bill Of Materials (checkbox)

In short the lesson learned: just because it is available in the item customization ui field list, does not mean it is available to the item form itself.